# Arranging $m$ edges on a graph of order $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am new to graph theory and combinatorics, and thought of a question yesterday that I couldn't find the answer to.

Is there a formula for counting the number of ways to arrange $m$ edges on a graph of order $n$?

Comment: Do you place limits on the type of graph? Has to be connected, simple, or no limits at all?

Comment: @Studentmath Yes I guess I do, I apologize for not stating that to begin with.  The graph does not have to be connected and it cannot contain any loops.  Although I am not familiar with the term simple.  What does that mean?

Comment: Usually it means a graph without loops (most definitions I saw at least), precisely what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{n}{2}$ possible ways to place the edges, so there are $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ possible arrangements of edges on a graph with $n$ vertices. You have $m$ such edges, so you simply want to consider subsets of size $m$. Thus, $\binom{ \binom{n}{2} } { m}$ gives you the count.